# How can i take health off a variable in my game

Tags: python

so i'm wanting to be able to display the user's health after they've been kicked, punched or slapped, but it doesn't keep it for some reason. I go to display it on a separate line, but it just says "100". Here's my code:

```
#random attack damage
player1Health = 100
player2Health = 100
punch = random.randint(5, 20)
kick = random.randint(5, 20)
slap = random.randint(5, 20)

#Checking if player chooses any of the attackTypes
player2HealthSlap = player2Health - slap
player2HealthPunch = player2Health - punch
player2HealthKick = player2Health - kick
if punch:
    puchAttack = print(
        f"Ouchh! {player1} just punched {player2}, and reduced their health amount to {player2HealthPunch}"
    )

elif kick:
    kickAttack = print(
        f"Wow! {player1} just kicked {player2}, reducing their health amount to {player2HealthKick}"
    )

elif slap:
    slapAttack = print(
        f"Oh no, that seemed to harm {player2} badly. Their health has reduced to       {player2HealthSlap}"
    )
```

I want to be able to call that variable, and have the amount of health player 1 did to player 2.

Comment: You never actually change `player1Health` or `player2Health`.

Comment: `kickAttack = print(...)` doesn't really make sense, `print` prints right away and returns `None` so you can't do anything with the resulting variables. The same applies to the other conditions.

Comment: "I go to display it on a separate line, but it just says "100"" What does this mean? What is "the user's health"? Please try to think logically about the code; and about what needs to happen, step by step; and about the *intended purpose* of each variable in the program. Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never change `player2Health`. Instead of storing `player2HealthSlap` etc. in separate variables, you could

```py
if punch:
    player2Health -= random.randint(5, 20) # subtract some HP from total
    print(f"[...] and reduced their health amount to {player2Health}")
```